# Add a device auth before shutting down the device without unlock

Tags: java, android

Hey guys I have an app that has an antitheft feature called `AnitPowerOff`, this feature needs to stop the user from shutting down the phone while in the locked state. Actually there is a CountDownTimer that times out and then the app locks the device. So I have this Samsung Galaxy A10 smartphone and it whenever I lock the screen and then try to shut down after I click the shut down button then it requires a password. Is there a way of programatically achieving this with Android Java. I have tried using a BroadcatReceiever but the app goes off and does not give the app time to execute the ode inside `OnReceive`. Here is the BroadcastReceiver attempt. I need to use a service that listens on shutdown events.

```
 public class ShutdownReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
       
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if (intent.Action == Intent.ActionShutdown)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(context,"Your trying to shut down the device",ToastLength.Long).Show();
                //require some form of pattern from the device
            }
        }
    }
```

The code is in C# but any Java code is welcome as I can easily convert it to C# for Xamarin Android. Is there a way to start a service that will capture when the shutdown button is clicked and then before the action goes through we tell the system to require password from the user?

Comment: BTW, according to my knowledge, you can't stop that from happening. Android can only notify you about that receiver. But, you _cant_ change the android functionality. Only you can change your app's functionality. But, the android allows us to be able to read these changes. Not write them

Comment: We cannot intercept the intent and do something before device goes off?

Comment: But it is achievable because I have a phone that does the same

Comment: `that does the same` becuase that is coded that way by Samsung. We can't do that.

Comment: `We cannot intercept the intent and do something before device goes off?` yes you can. But, what can u do when the drive is switched off?

Comment: AND, also, you can intercept the intent. But, you can't stop the task from happening. You can surely do something before device turns off but can't stop it from turning off

Comment: Heading over to Samsung devops to get some help.

Comment: Phone manufacturers modify the version of Android their devices run, so they're able to add functionality like changing the UI when you try to power off, and they're able to grant their own apps privileges that a normal app can't get, without root anyway. So just because a phone has a feature baked in, it doesn't mean you (a random person) can write an app that does the same - in fact it's very unlikely for something like this, where you're interfering with system functionality